# Nextjs, import styles from node_modules fails in production

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

Nextjs is not loading css for specific packages in production and yet works fine in development even after following [Nextjs documents](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#import-styles-from-node_modules). As is suggested by several devs.

This is happening for several packages i have installed.

```
in _app.js
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css";

in pages/about.js where am using the carousel
import {Carousel} from 'react-responsive-carousel';
    
    <div> 
<Carousel>
    ...
 </Carousel>
 </div>
```

The above setup works fine in development but cannot get it to work in production.

I should note, that many such questions are not receiving the attention and response.

Comment: Why not just print  this conditionally via a link tag in your `_document.jsx` ?
`  return <link href={<YOUR CSS>} rel="stylesheet" />;`  

OR package it into your CSS file

Comment: Packaging it into my css file does not work in my production either

Comment: Unable to replicate your issue. [Demo](https://next-carousel-example.vercel.app/) and [Demo Source](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/next-carousel-example)

Comment: I have looked it up and cannot seem to figure out whats wrong with my setup. It fails for other packages that require .css files loaded from node_modules

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); otherwise, it'll be impossible to determine where the problem lies.

Comment: Would an upgrade of nextjs fix this?